# return value of lseek()

Tags: c, linux, file, lseek

I got confused about `lseek()`'s return value(which is new file offset)

I have the text file (Its name is prwtest). Its contents are written to a to z.

And, the code what I wrote is following,

```
  1 #include <unistd.h>
  2 #include <fcntl.h>
  3 #include <stdlib.h>
  4 #include <stdio.h>
  5 #include <string.h>
  6 
  7 #define BUF 50
  8 
  9 int main(void)
 10 {
 11         char buf1[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 12         char buf2[BUF];
 13         int fd;
 14         int read_cnt;
 15         off_t cur_offset;
 16 
 17         fd=openat(AT_FDCWD, "prwtest", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
 18         cur_offset=lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
 19         //pwrite(fd, buf1, strlen(buf1), 0);
 20         //write(fd, buf1, strlen(buf1));
 21         //cur_offset=lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
 22 
 23         printf("current offset of file prwtest: %d \n", cur_offset);
 24 
 25         exit(0);
 26 }
```

On the line number `17`, I use flag `O_APPEND`, so the prwtest's current file offset is taken from i-node's current file size. (It's 26).

On the line number `18`, I use `lseek()` which is used by SEEK_CUR, and the offset is 0.

But the result value `cur_offset` is 0. (I assume that it must be 26, because SEEK_CUR indicates current file offset.)
However, `SEEK_END` gives me what I thought, `cur_offset` is 26.

Why the `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);` gives me return value 0, not 26?

Comment: Just a side note, since you use O_CREAT in the flags, you MUST also supply a 4. argument to openat(), the file permission mode to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, on Linux, your commented-out code won't work as you expect.  This code:

```
 17         fd=openat(AT_FDCWD, "prwtest", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND);
 18         cur_offset=lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
 19         pwrite(fd, buf1, strlen(buf1), 0);
```

will fail to write the contents of `buf1` at the beginning of the file (unless the file is empty).

[`pwrite` on Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) is buggy:

> **BUGS**
>
> POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should
>   have no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data. 
>   However, on Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()`
>   appends data to the end of the file, regardless of the value of
>   *offset*.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with `open()` / `openat()`, not `lseek()`.

From the `open()` manpage, emphasis mine:

> **O_APPEND**
>
> The file is opened in append mode. **Before each write(2),** the file offset is positioned at the end of the file, as if with lseek(2).

Since you don't write to the file, the offset is never repositioned to the end of the file.

---

While we're at it, you should be *closing* the file before ending the program...

---

Actually, while we're *really* at it, if you *do* `#include <stdio.h>` already, why not use the standard's file I/O (`fopen()` / `fseek()` / `fwrite()`) instead of the POSIX-specific stuff? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`O_APPEND` takes effect before each write to the file, not when opening file.

Therefore right after the open the position remains `0` but if you invoke write, the `lseek` on `SEEK_CUR` will return correct value.